# OSX drivers for Razer Blackwidow Keyboard

Tags: macos, drivers, razer-keyboard

Does anyone know where to find OSX drivers for the Razer BlackWidow keyboard (official or otherwise)? I bought it on a whim (love clicky keys), but can't find any drivers for my Mac to make use of the hotkeys on the left of the keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

There are no official Razer drivers available on their site. It seems they announced drivers 6 months ago though.

> YYYYYEEESSS!!!! "There will be a fully Mac-compatible driver for the Razer BlackWidow"

(user comment on [a Razer facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=455672730942))

---

Try using [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html), a commercial third-party USB device utility.

> The USB Overdrive is a device driver for Mac OS X that handles any USB mouse / trackball / joystick / gamepad / **media keyboard** and any Bluetooth mouse from any manufacturer and lets you configure them either globally or on a per-application, per-device basis.

(emphasis by me)

Comment: I doubt that USB Overdrive will help it is for mice, although it is probably worth a shot.

Comment: @Mark Edited my post. See the quote.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. USB Overdrive detects the Blackwidow, but it doesn't detect the 5 macro keys.  It seems that I need specialised drivers to make use of them (which are only available on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

On windows, there seems to be a separate driver for the macro keys, and the keys are *not* detected on windows. I've tried a few things on [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/342107/getting-macro-keys-from-a-razer-blackwidow-to-work-on-linux) but i've not had luck.

There does seem to be a driver for the mac versions at the [razer](http://www.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=198&pcid=196&nav=0,77,191,196) site that might be worth a shot.

Edit: from a quick messabout - using the driver for the OS X variant of the black window ultimate, with a regular black widow ultimate , on the fly macro editing and creation, as well as Key remapping,seems to work.

I would warn that some keys are mismapped, and it may take some trial and error to work out what key is what

<kbd>F13</kbd> on the configurator maps to <kbd>M1</kbd>, <kbd>F14</kbd> to <kbd>M2</kbd>. <kbd>f15</kbd> to <kbd>M3</kbd> and and so on (so all 5 macro keys do seem to work ) and i have not been able to work out where the physical scr lk and pause break keys map to (wierdly, game mode is toggled by fn f1 as well as fn f11 and fn pausebreak seems to open the shut down menu) - so the image on the driver/configurator is ***incorrect***  with a 'pc' model blackwidow. I'll need to poke to actually work out which is which, but the functions DO seem to work for most part - i tested reprogramming keys, and launching software.

EDIT: As per Tyler's answer - this is *not* fully supported, and DOES NOT WORK PERFECTLY. DEBUGGING REQUIRED. DO NOT ATTEMPT UNLESS YOU ARE WILLING TO REVERSE ENGINEER THE KEY LAYOUT.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Mac OS X user, currently 10.6.8. I have the regular, Windows-layout, Razer Blackwidow  keyboard and have been using it on my Mac, hoping Razer would eventually come out with drivers.

I have tried everything I could to get the macro buttons to just be recognized, but gave up. I now understand that you need the Razer driver on your computer to get those to work, so now that there is a Mac layout keyboard and a driver for it that is made for OS X, I decided to just try it after reading the above post.

- Now, with the driver my keyboard has been remapped on this computer so that out of all the `F`-keys only two will register. `F3` registers on the computer as `F9`, and `F4` as `F12`.
- The macro keys work... sort of, they work but half are mapped to redundant keys. It is completely fine on any other computer, just mine is screwed.

I tried flashing the firmware just now to no avail. I have concluded that my problem will most likely never be solved because razer released their Mac layout keyboards and drivers for those, so they have probably aren't making drivers just for me on my Mac with old, non-Mac keyboard.

*P.S.* [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) allows you to program the media keys (the `Fn+F` keys that control music) on a Razer Blackwidow without any OS X Razer drivers. With the Mac driver you can remap keys, but I wouldn't trust that without the Mac layout.

I never should have installed the Mac driver...

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer - the mismapped keys are a known issue, and the layout is not properly debugged but i don't have enough time on a mac (i am a windows/linux user mostly)to work it out. It is *not* a firmware error, since it works fine on my windows system. Its probably possible to reverse engineer a driver to get the macro keys to work with some flavour of libusb but i have neither the time or the skills to do that. I will update my answer when i have time and mac access, since i have *some* idea on how to work out which key goes where.

Answer (score 0):

There are official drivers for the Mac-layout of the keyboard [here](http://www.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=198&pcid=196&nav=0,77,191,196). As far as I'm aware, there aren't any official drivers for the Windows layout. I had some luck using the Mac-layout drivers with my Windows-layout keyboard, but there were admittedly some odd behaviors for the keys that aren't matched up properly.

Even without full functionality, it's a glorious keyboard.