# How to enable Razer BlackWidow macro keys on Windows without install Razer Synapse?

Tags: windows, macros, razer-keyboard

I found out how to enable Razer BlackWidow macro keys on Linux, and I want to enable them on Windows as well, without installing any Razer driver.

Please help me. I want use macro keys with Autohotkey.

Here is a guide for Linux: [Getting macro keys from a Razer BlackWidow to work on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/342107/getting-macro-keys-from-a-razer-blackwidow-to-work-on-linux)

Comment: There isn't any reason the Python code submitted for that answer wouldn't work on Windows. Why are you against installing the driver?

Comment: i build from haskell code here: https://github.com/tuxmark5/EnableRazer but not work, error error error... HID keyboards and mice cannot be accessed using the native HID driver as Windows reserves exclusive access to them.

Comment: You sure about that. I am pretty sure Razer's drivers are HID drivers.