# Can I bind keys from a specific device to shortcuts in Linux, without affecting other keyboards

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, razer-keyboard

I recently picked up a Razer Orbweaver which works pretty well with my windows installation through the Razer Synapse software. While I can't switch between profiles in Linux, the corresponding keys that Linux detects to a specific physical key is the same regardless of the profile the keypad is on. Unlike a Blackwidow, from what I can tell all (or most) of the keys work, and there's no need for any joojoo. However the fixed key-map results in a dilemma if I wanted to use it the same way I would in windows

Is there some way I can map *specific* keys on the keypad (for example <kbd>W</kbd> for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>), so that I can use the Orbweaver to trigger off macros (but not on another keyboard on the same system? IIRC xbindkeys is system wide, and I need it to a specific device.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, but I'm doubtful that this is distro specific. As with my [blackwidow question](https://superuser.com/questions/342107/getting-macro-keys-from-a-razer-blackwidow-to-work-on-linux),  I would be willing to test anything that makes sense on a Linux system if I have detailed instructions - *however* anyone can replicate this with a second keyboard, since thats what this is in effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to accomplish this using `xkbcomp`.  The ArchWiki has [detailed instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension) on how to set this up, including a section on [multiple keyboards](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension#Multiple_keyboards).

Comment: Nice! Might take a day or two for me to actually test this out. Would you mind if I edit in the details of the steps I took to get it working? We don't like link only answers here, but this really looks like it could work.

Comment: @ Sure.  I would've put it in a comment but I don't have enough points to comment yet.

Comment: Any update on this? I've been able to use xkbcomp to get simple keyboard remapping for a single device. However, I would like to get 1:N key maps (e.g., pressing a button on the second keyboard sets off a key combination like Ctrl+C) or running custom commands, which would probably be done best with xbindkeys. I also considered using xkbcomp to remap keys on the second keyboard to custom keysyms and then tried to remap those, but it seems like xbindkeys doesn't seem to work with the remapped keysyms.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but there's a new app called KeyboardingMaster that runs through java and is cross platform, it supports a few keypads now recently including the Razer Orbweaver (Tartarus and Nostromo too)! It works perfectly in Ubuntu, I have now fully ditched Windows! It supports Keysets with dynamic switch much like what the Synapse driver offers, the one thing it can't do yet is interact with the device LEDs.

Comment: This *reads* like spam. Are you affiliated with the app in any way?

Comment: I'm intregued but more information would be nice - How does this work? What do I need to do, and what prerequisites are there? Does this work as a regular user, or do I need to fire it up as root? More critically *where do I find this software*?

Comment: This isn't spam lol! :P I recently found it myself and was so pleased with it that I decided to go through all the forum posts, etc where people had the same issue but no solution and post about it. Here's a link: https://sites.google.com/site/keyboardingmaster/home

Basically the app runs with Java and creates what i think is a Java input device which is a remapping of the device, it allows for profiles and keysets and even works with Dropbox where you can save your profiles and use them across devices.